# How to perform the "in" query on jpa's @ManyToOne JoinColumn without querying the entity

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have an entity like:

```java
@Entity
class Blog{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    // ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private User author;
}
```

And I want to perform an "in" query on the `author` column, so I wrote my `BlogRepository` like:

```java
public interface BlogRepository extends JpaRepository<Blog, Long>, CustomizedBlogRepository {

    Page<Blog> findByUserIn(Collection<User> users, Pageable pageable);
}
```

This works, however, I need to perform two queries for one request, that is to query the `User` entity from `UserRepository` to get `Collection<User> users`.
Because in many situation, all I want is semantic like:

```sql
select * from blog where author_id in (some_id_list);
```

So is there anyway in jpa to let me perform query like below without querying the `User` entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Order` part of your method gets in the way. Since you don't want the results ordered, you can use this:

```
public interface BlogRepository extends JpaRepository<Blog, Long>, CustomizedBlogRepository {

    Page<Blog> findByUser_IdIn(Collection<Long> userId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: Can i write my custom JPQL ```@Query``` to achieve this?

Comment: @user8510613 I must have misread the question. I've edited my answer - is this what you're looking for?

Comment: This is what i am looking for

Comment: @user8510613 I'm glad I could help. Consider upvoting / marking the answer as correct;>

Comment: besides, what if i want to just save the user_id in ```Blog``` entity?

Comment: And the problem here is? You can write analogous jpql update query for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can also write custom JPQL

public interface BlogRepository extends JpaRepository, CustomizedBlogRepository {

```
@Query("select b from Blog b LEFT JOIN b.author.authorId in :authorIds")
Page<Blog> getByUsersByIds(List<Integer> authorIds, Pageable pageable);
```

}

Here you can change authorId to any Id of User table, which you have created.And you can also try **JOIN** instead of **LEFT JOIN**